# Slick Slider not showing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

Slick slider does not init propely
I think that slick is getting his parent width incorectly. But I am unsure of what is happening.
Im under this impresion because when i "inspect element" I see `width:35000 px`;

I written this simple code for simplicity

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="AboutUsSlider" style="width: 90%; display: inline-block;">
            <div><img src="/images/banners/727X300.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="/images/banners/727X300.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="/images/banners/727X300.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="/images/banners/727X300.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="/images/banners/727X300.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="/images/banners/727X300.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="/images/banners/727X300.jpg"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AboutUsSlider").slick({
        rtl:true,
        infinite:true,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        dots: true,
        speed: 500,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        arrows: true
    });
});
</script>
```

If you guys would like to see it live,
 [new.jccayer.com/test.php](http://new.jccayer.com/test.php)

any one has an idea why this is happening ? Any help/comment is apreciated!

EDIT

I took the example they ship in the downloaded "Slick" .zip
posted online at [new.jccayer.com/test.html](http://new.jccayer.com/test.html)
We can compare it to [new.jccayer.com/test.php](http://new.jccayer.com/test.php) Witch is mine

Both pages use files on my server. So no cdn. and both same files.
Meaning that only the source code in this page is somewhere wrong. ( because example work )

Still I can't figure out what is diferent from the two file. Im I becoming blind because of how long I have been trying to make this work ?

Any one?

Comment: Got a 404 on the link. Also, please post the actual code so we can diagnose the problem, and only the relevant code.

Comment: Its the actual code, I created a page just for this so we only have code releated to this.

Page should work now.

Comment: Did you include jquery migrate file? I dont see it in your source code

Comment: No But its'nt required according to the example they give in the .zip you download when getting Slick.
Any how. I just tried to include it and still nothing.. We can see the it from the link in the OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to get this working locally by getting rid of the rtl option - Can you test and see if getting rid of that option works for you? So the code would just be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AboutUsSlider").slick({
        infinite:true,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        dots: true,
        speed: 500,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        useTransform:false,
//      autoplay: true,
//      autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        arrows: true
    });
});
```

If you don't want to get rid of any options, see the slick documentation at http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ to see how to handle right-to-left -

> Note: the HTML tag or the parent of the slider must have the attribute
>   "dir" set to "rtl".

So then, your div would just have dir="rtl" in the tag. Both work. If you have any issues let me know!

Comment: Wow! lol. What is the point of having this property if its not working!
Thanks! ALOT I have been on this for 3 hours! I never though of removing that particular property since I need it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that setting the CSS parent's overflow to hidden can help occasionally, too.

```
.parent-foo{
postion:relative; /* not always necessary */ 
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This one helped me. Thanks!